# Coldfusion Cookies from javascript function

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

What would be the best way to handle ColdFusion Cookies from a javascript function?

I need to *get* and *set* the Cookie's value.

I guess there is an alternative solution to using `document.cookie` ?

Comment: The best way using coldfusion would be to use ajax to make a call to a cfc, but I'm not sure if that's what you're after.

Comment: Hmmmm.... if you set a cookie in Javascript it is available to CF in subsequent requests (it's sent in the header). IF you set a cookie in CF it is available to Javascript (it becomes a part of the dom). So this question is sort of odd. To "get" at a CF cookie from JS you would use document.cookie - yes? Not sure exactly what the question is here.

Comment: In other words, what's the best approch: setting via document.cookie or via the cfcookie tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the answer is if you're in javascript you'd use document.cookie and if you're in CFML you'd use cfcookie.

I suppose it depends on when you're trying to do this really--if you're doing this in a block of javascript when the page loads then you *could* use cfcookie since that would get parsed as the page renders, but after the page loads of course you can't use cfcookie without another page load (if that makes sense).

On the flip side if you're doing some behind the scenes processing in CFML of course you'd have to use cfcookie since doing in the javascript way might not be possible given the situation.

Honestly even in situations where you could do either it doesn't matter. Both do the same thing so use whatever one makes most sense or makes the code most readable given the situation.